# Sort data from an external API in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I'm currently working on a test function for Wordpress which 'GET's data from an external API. Its successfully getting the data but I wish to order the data list by the 'name' field in ASC order within the foreach loop.

I've tried adding usort, rsort etc before the foreach loop but it has no effect. Just wondering if anyone has experience of this, thanks.

```
function api_demo($atts) {
  $args = array( 
    'headers' => array(
      'Authorization' => '****'
    )
  ); 

  $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://****', $args ); 
  $lists = json_decode( $response['body'], true );

  if( !empty( $lists ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $lists["data"] as $list ) {
      echo '<li>' . $list['name'] . '</li>';
    } 
    echo '</ul>'; 
  }
}
```

Heres the output from $list:

```
array(2) { ["data"]=> array(12) { [0]=> array(89) { ["id"]=> string(6) "479136" ["url"]=> string(43) "app.celoxis.com/psa/projects****" ["name"]=> string(14) "Server Maintan" etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort` function.
Starting array:

```
$array = Array (
    Array (
        "id" => "1",
        "url" => "url 1",
        "name" => "hi!"
        ),
    Array (
        "id" => "2",
        "url" => "url 2",
        "name" => "by the way"
        ),
    Array (
        "id" => "3",
        "url" => "url 3",
        "name" => "hello"
        ),
    Array (
        "id" => "4",
        "url" => "url 4",
        "name" => "again!"
        ),
);
```

Code to sort the starting multidimensional array by name:

```
function name_compare($element1, $element2) {
    return strcasecmp($element1['name'], $element2['name']);
}

// Sort the array
usort($array, 'name_compare');

// Print the array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array)
```